# How do I get a new skin?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I get new player skins in Minecraft PE?

Comment: Please don't just spam emoticons.

Comment: @galacticninja that method was for an older version that didn't support changing skins. Now that you can do it natively this is the method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go on the internet and find a player skin that's compatible with the PC Version, Then you can add it to the PE version by downloading the skin to the mobile device you have the game on, then going to the game settings and clicking on the skin tab.[image: Skin Options Screen]

Then click custom and choose the skin you downloaded.

Hope this helps!